# div automatically going to the top

Tags: html, css

Okay, I've seen loads of information about this, but none of the suggested fixes worked for me, or perhaps I just didn't properly understand, so if someone could break this down elementary for me that'd be great, or point me to another link that does. I have a series of divs to make my header, a main container with the logo inside floating left, and then another container floating right, that works all fine, but the internal "menu" container contains two divs in it, one supposed to be at the top, the other at the bottom... to visualize it, its login or register links at the top, and a series of menu links at the bottom. The problem is the ones that are supposed to be at the bottom are actually going to the top, right under the register and login links. If that didn't give you a visual picture, then here is the actual header http://www.sunnahspace.com/pages/header.php i've tried loads of stuff, maybe I've just been trying it wrong though. i've tried the whole, position absolute stuff and honestly i don't even know what that means, but I get the feeling I'm headed in the right direction. Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
.header_links {
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header_menu {
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header {
    background-image:url(../img/header_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:111px;
    }
#logo {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    }
#header_menu_container {
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:111px;
    }
#header_menu_top {
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:top
    }
#header_menu_bottom {
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:bottom
    }
</style> 
<div id="header"> 
<div id="logo"> <a href="index.php"><img src="../img/logo.png" width="390" height="105" alt="SunnahSpace"></a> 
</div> 
<div id="header_menu_container"> 
<div id="header_menu_top" align="right"><a href="login.php" class="header_links">Login</a> <span class="header_links">|</span> <span class="header_links"><a href="join.php" class="header_links">Join</a></span> 
</div> 
<div id="header_menu_bottom" align="right" style="vertical-align:bottom"><a href="../index.php" class="header_links"><span class="header_menu">Home</span></a><span class="header_menu"> | <a href="profile.php" class="header_menu">Profile</a> | <a href="about.php" class="header_menu">About</a> | <a href="contact.php" class="header_menu">Contact</a></span> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 



     <style type="text/css"> 
.header_links {
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header_menu {
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header {
    background-image:url(../img/header_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:111px;
    }
#logo {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    }
#header_menu_container {
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:111px;
    }
#header_menu_top {
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:top
    }
#header_menu_bottom {
    margin-top:10px;
    vertical-align:bottom
    }
</style> 
<div id="header"> 
<div id="logo"> <a href="index.php"><img src="../img/logo.png" width="390" height="105" alt="SunnahSpace"></a> 
</div> 
<div id="header_menu_container"> 
<div id="header_menu_top" align="right"><a href="login.php" class="header_links">Login</a> <span class="header_links">|</span> <span class="header_links"><a href="join.php" class="header_links">Join</a></span> 
</div> 
<div id="header_menu_bottom" align="right" style="vertical-align:bottom"><a href="../index.php" class="header_links"><span class="header_menu">Home</span></a><span class="header_menu"> | <a href="profile.php" class="header_menu">Profile</a> | <a href="about.php" class="header_menu">About</a> | <a href="contact.php" class="header_menu">Contact</a></span> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: no, i want it to appear on the bottom-inside of the header, im going to add a margin to it naturally to keep it from being on the line, but right now the bottom menu is immediately below the top menu, if you looked at it then i want it just above that bar on the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following to your styles

```
#header_menu_bottom {
bottom: 15px;
position: absolute;
text-align: right;
width: 300px;
right: 0;
}
#header_menu_container {
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: that didn't really do anything, should I delete everything else in those styles and just have this in it?

Comment: @Nathan This should work; did you add it after the rest of your CSS rules?

Comment: yes, and i tried deleting the rules and just using this but then the bottom menu disappeared entirely, maybe i should delete a few that may contradict the above?

Comment: oh i figured it out, the was a missing ";" in the menu_bottom style, works like a charm, thanks! Can you explain what it was that makes it do that, i'd like to be able to know when to do it in the future rather than just parrot it if you know what i mean.

Comment: @nathan, check these links http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ , http://css-tricks.com/1191-absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: wow, that site is going in my bookmarks! so helpful, thanks :D